# Combining s/and with s/or in Clojure spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I want to write a spec for a map that either has the key `:rule/children` or has two keys - `:condition/field` and `:condition/predicate`. This is what I have tried:

```
(s/keys :req [(s/or :children :rule/children :condition (s/and :condition/field :condition/predicate))])
```

It results in the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: all keys must be namespace-qualified keywords
(every? (fn* [p1__1917#] (c/and (keyword? p1__1917#) (namespace p1__1917#))) (concat req-keys req-un-specs opt opt-un))
```

I know that for `s/or` each path must be named. Here there are two paths - this map can either have `:children` or be a `:condition`. It is a condition only if it has the two keys `:condition/field` and `:condition/predicate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `keys` specs you can use plain `or` and `and` to do this:

```
(s/def ::map-spec
  (s/keys :req [(or :rule/children (and :condition/field :condition/predicate))]))

(s/conform ::map-spec {:rule/children 1}) ;; valid
(s/conform ::map-spec {:condition/field 1}) ;; invalid
(s/conform ::map-spec {:condition/field 1 :condition/predicate 2}) ;; valid
```

Comment: Here just verifying the existence of keywords in a map. If those keywords themselves have specs associated with them then presumably plain `or` and `and` won't be enough. I'll try with `s/or` and `s/and` for that case. I can feel another SO question coming on...

Comment: Actually just `or` and `and` are fine, even when the keywords are turned into proper spec keywords e.g. `:condition/field` to `i.am.a.spec.condition/field`.